# Layout is not aligned because of lacking float

Tags: css, html

The code below is from W3CSchool example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:500px">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:20%;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br>
HTML<br>
CSS<br>
JavaScript</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:80%;">
Content goes here</div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;text-align:center;">
Copyright © W3Schools.com</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can copy the code and paste it to the editor below:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_divs

I have already specified the width of "menu" to 20% and "content" to 80%, why at the right side of "content" has a blank area?

It will only align properly if I add "float:left" in the css style of "content". I can't understand why it behave like that. Anyone can explain?

Thanks for help.

Comment: everything on w3schools.com is not correct, please keep this in mind, some developer call it w3fools.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the width of the container for `menu` and `content` is set to `500px`.

Set it to `100%` if you want it to take the whole page:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
```

Also if you want the content to simply take all the remaining space, don't assign it a width:

```
<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; height:200px">Content goes here</div>
```

Here's the full working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:100%">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:20%;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br>
HTML<br>
CSS<br>
JavaScript</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px">
Content goes here</div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;text-align:center;">
Copyright © W3Schools.com</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeap, this is the answer! +1

Comment: It' ll solve the problem. but menu is overlapping content. It'll not create issue if only text is there in content but if you apply background-image or increase height of content.. it'll create issues [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x35SL/)

Answer (score 1):

There is blank area at right of page because your floating div is **overlapping** your content div because floating divs always float above the other divs (Try removing background-color of menu to see example). When you apply float right/left to your content div, it also floats with menu div hence occupies all the space.

please refer to [This site](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

for more information on **float**.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

DIVs are block elements. This means that 2 DIVs are displayed one bellow another, if not use `float` , `position:absolute;`, or `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use 'float' style express this div present external for 'inline' and present inside for 'block',and will affect the back of the element. so if content right display you can use 'float:left;width:80%' and 'float:left;width:80%'. In fact, this is 'display:inline-block', but according to my experience, it will produce the browser bug.